# selecting only few columns with criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria, criteria-api

I have the database query such as ,..

```
select aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd from ioa_book
```

as shown it is hitting the table ioa_book and only selecting few columns , the corresponding pojo name is boop .. and now I want to convert it into criteria of hibernate one but it loads all the columns that i do not want , i still want to use criteria and with selected columns itself , please advise how to achieve this..

so I have gone by this way...

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(boop.class);
 List<boop> books = criteria.list();
```

please advise

Answer (score 0):

```
criteria.setProjection(
    Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("aaa"))
        .add(Projections.property("bbb"))
        .add(Projections.property("ccc")) 
    );
List<Object[]> result = criteria.list();
```

This is [documented](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-projection).