# how to exclude certain columns being returned in hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I referred to the below one for adding a specific columns to be returned in hibernate.
[How to return an entity with chosen columns using Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950718/how-to-return-an-entity-with-chosen-columns-using-criteria)

However in mycase the exclusion is small so i would like to see if i can give the list of columns to be excluded in the result.

Is there a optimal way to do it in hibernate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** There is no way to provide exclusions in Hibernate Criteria.

Several other ways of inclusions are below. It is totally your choice.

1. One way of doing this is creating a light weight hibernate mapping object with only columns that are required.
2. Use HQL to get the columns that you need like this ' Select c.col1,c.col2 from Columns c'
3. Construct HQL at run time, have a template prepared like below

   > 'Select ' + userDefColumns + ' from Columns c'; // pass the
   >   userDefColumns at run time.
4. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012235/selecting-only-few-columns-with-criteria)